# How to pull images to docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I read the tutorial in [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/),and it show me can use these commands to pull image to docker registry,like that:

```
docker pull ubuntu && docker tag ubuntu localhost:5000/batman/ubuntu
docker push localhost:5000/batman/ubuntu
```

I want to know whether I need to tag already image when I pull image to registry. Is it just only way to pull image to docker registry?

Answer (score 0):

You always need to tag your images first with a tag containing repository information. Then you can push them to your private registry. Please refer also to [this blogpost](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/docker-registry-run-private-docker-image-repository/).